# How to cope with this error while compiling latex with vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, xetex

I followed several tutorials on the Internet and tried to build a latex environment in vscode. However, after I've installed everything and started running a `.tex` file, it came up with the following error:

```
Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!
xelatex: Bad parameter value.
xelatex: Data: font_mem_size
```

source code `test.tex`: (I put it in a folder on desktop)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

I tried Google, but didn't find any effective approach. I also restarted my computer and reinstalled `MiKTeX`, but nothing changed.

By the way: I installed `LaTeX workshop`, `MiKTeX` and `Strawberry Perl` (just following the tutorial) and added this into the `settings.json` of vscode.

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "command": "xelatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "bibtex",
            "command": "bibtex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex"
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "xe->bib->xe->xe",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex",
                "bibtex",
                "xelatex",
                "xelatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdf->bib->pdf->pdf",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "bibtex",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onFileChange",
    "latex-workshop.message.error.show": false,
    "latex-workshop.message.warning.show": false,
```

**Update**: the issue was solved by reinstalling MiKTeX and resetting its environment variables in `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was eventually solved by reinstalling `MiKTeX` and resetting its environment variables in `PATH`. (Another way is to directly install `MiKTeX` in its recommended directory, which is how I solved the problem.) In addition, the code I added in the `settings.json` should be discarded (or vscode will report errors).

Answer (score 0):

RUN as Administrator (and check in the properties of the mik-tex.exe file "always run as Administrator"). It finally works for me.